# Get the id of a row when UNIQUE KEY is violated

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table `user`. It has columns `id` and `email`.

USER TABLE

```
id | email
1  | xxx@gmail.com
2  | yyy@gmail.com
```

The `id` is a `PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT` and the `email` is an `UNIQUE KEY`.
When I insert a new row in the table and there is a `DUPLICATE KEY` exception thrown. I want to fetch the `id` on which the `DUPLICATE KEY` exception was thrown.

Right now I am doing this -

```
BEGIN
DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR 1062
    BEGIN
        SELECT id
        INTO id
        FROM user
        WHERE email = 'xxx@gmail.com';
    END;
    INSERT INTO user
    (email)
    VALUES
    ('xxx@gmail.com');

SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID() INTO id;
END;
```

I want to know if there is a better way to do this. That is to avoid scanning the table again to get the id for which it had already scanned to check the uniqueness of the email.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/insert-on-duplicate.html), then [get the autoincremented id as usual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/getting-unique-id.html):

> If a table contains an `AUTO_INCREMENT` column and [`INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/insert-on-duplicate.html) inserts or updates a row, the [`LAST_INSERT_ID()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id) function returns the `AUTO_INCREMENT` value. Exception: For updates, [`LAST_INSERT_ID()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id) is not meaningful prior to MySQL 5.1.12. However, you can work around this by using [`LAST_INSERT_ID(expr)`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id). Suppose that `id` is the `AUTO_INCREMENT` column. To make [`LAST_INSERT_ID()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id) meaningful for updates, insert rows as follows:
>
> ```
> INSERT INTO table (a,b,c) VALUES (1,2,3)
>   ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE id=LAST_INSERT_ID(id), c=3;
> ```

Comment: I do not want to update. I just want the id for which the email column gave a DUPLICATE KEY value.

Comment: @Juniad: So just do `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE id=LAST_INSERT_ID(id)` as shown.  Nothing will be changed, but `LAST_INSERT_ID()` will give you the ID you're after.

Comment: Wrong. This will indeed update the `Auto_increment` value, as described here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12692003/avoid-increasing-auto-increment-value-when-using-last-insert-id

Comment: @NOPslider: I didn't realise that - thanks for the heads-up. Clearly, my comment "*nothing will be changed*" was over-zealous: as you point out, whilst no data will be changed, the next auto-increment value is updated.  Sadly, I can no longer edit that comment, but this discussion should help to avoid any future misunderstanding.  I do however feel the downvote (from whomever) is a bit OTT given that the above answer still fully and correctly addresses the OP's problem (which was about how one can obtain the ID of the relevant record, whether newly inserted or pre-existing).

Comment: Sorry, that was an accidental click. Can't undo it :(

Answer (score 1):

In scaning by `UNIQUE KEY` `BTREE` is used so it's quite fast.

Don't you want check for existing of value by yourself in additional `select` query

Comment: +1 Checking prior to the insert is a far better solution that trying to insert and catching the error.

Comment: I want to know the id of the row where the UNIQUE KEY is being thrown.