# Avoid increasing Auto_increment value?

Tags: mysql, insert, duplicates, last-insert-id

In MySQL, you can insert a row and update the 'last insert ID' at the same time. I'm using this trick to be able to insert items conditionally (uniqueness) and still get the unique ID in *all* cases.

The code below works. The problem is that the `ON DUPLICATE KEY` statement also updates the `Auto_increment` value. Is it possible to avoid that?

```
CREATE TABLE T(
    id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    X VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL UNIQUE
) ENGINE = InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO T(X) VALUES ('x') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE id = LAST_INSERT_ID(id);
SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID();
INSERT INTO T(X) VALUES ('x') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE id = LAST_INSERT_ID(id);
SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID();
```

Now we have one entry with `id=1`. However, the **next** entry will have `id=3` since the `Auto_increment` value was updated when the second `INSERT` failed. This can be checked as follows:

```
SELECT Auto_increment FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_name = 't'
     AND table_schema = DATABASE();
```

**Q:** Is it possible to use this trick (or equivalent) and keep the `Auto_increment` value? Obviously, in this case, it doesn't need to get updated.

Comment: There may well be valid reasons, but I'm curious: why do you care what `AUTO_INCREMENT` value is assigned, so long as it is unique?

Comment: There are valid reasons (as listed here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7087869/mysql-insert-on-duplicate-update-adds-one-to-the-autoincrement). Still, I don't like my ID running away without a purpose :)

Comment: This is due to neither `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` nor `LAST_INSERT_ID()`: it [also arises](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9751e/1/0) with `INSERT IGNORE` (although multiple insertions [behave curiously](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ec62c/1), with the counter incremented for subsequent insertions but no gaps within the records inserted).  The [accepted answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7100901/623041) of the question to which you've just linked explains this behaviour nicely.

Comment: Why would you spend time and effort avoiding gaps in your auto-increment ids?

Comment: Your title is misleading: using LAST_INSERT_ID() does not increase anything, it just returns the last generated id.

Comment: Maybe I wouldn't. It's more like I want to know if this is by design, and why it is so.